# Trouble allocating very large objects in Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2013/2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, memory, out-of-memory, windows-10

I am accustomed to writing C# code in Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop 2013 that allocates large objects (e.g., that take an 8GB 64-bit system from 40% memory usage to 90%), using the usual trick of <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true"/> and configuring the build for x64 systems. This worked fine until upgrading to Windows 10. Now, before system memory usage gets anywhere near 90%, either Visual Studio crashes, or I get an out of memory error, or the or the system hangs completely and requires a hard restart. It doesn't seem to matter whether I use VS 2013 or 2015, whether or not I "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" in Debug settings, or whether I run in Debug or Release mode. Does anyone know of a solution or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

If your "system is hanging" means your operating system is crashing, then I suspect a hardware issue. Run the built-in Windows memory test on your next reboot.

Comment: This is just nonsense. OP is completely allocating memory. The Visual Studio debugger has a hard time evaluating it all and hangs or crashes.